# Repeating tablix header on each page, but want to change heading on repeated rows second page

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report with a simple tablix control where (using advanced mode for row groups / column groups) I've set one of the rows to repeat on each page. I was hoping that when a heading is repeated on a new page I could use an expression to change the column heading to the original column heading plus some extra text (for e.g. on page one the heading would be 'heading' but on page two the heading would be 'heading cont..').

Is this possible and if so how would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the group header is formatted only once per group and simply repeated on each page. For instance, add the following code to your report in the custom code (right-click report, choose Properties and select the Code tab):

```
Dim Ctr As Integer

Public Function ShowCtr As Integer
    Ctr = Ctr + 1
    ShowCtr = Ctr
End Function
```

Then add this formula to a cell in the group header:

```
=Code.ShowCtr
```

You'll see that the value is the same for each group header on each page for that group - it doesn't get recalculated every time it prints. So we can't use the group header.

Chris Hays has a way to do this using the table header on his blog: ["Continued" Header on Subsequent Pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2006/09/27/continuedheader.aspx)

Comment: Appreciated, definitely have me headed in the right direction. Thank-you